# Not able to include php file in roundcube template

Tags: php, roundcube

I am integrating the roundcude email client to my site.

It works fine but when i am integrating it into my site , i am having the issues in including files.

My home path is `/home/alpine/public_html/RIO/dashboard/round_email`

I want to include the `header.php(/home/alpine/public_html/RIO/dashboard/setting/header.php)` file in roundcude `header.html(/home/alpine/public_html/RIO/dashboard/round_email/skins/larry/includes/header.html)` file

I tried the roundcude code for including but it doesn't work.

I used the code as `<roundcude:include file="/../setting/header.php"/>`

Even its not showing any error.

Please give me the answer for this

Answer (score 0):

In `/config/main.inc.php` set `$rcmail_config['skin_include_php']` to **true**.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sintax:

```
<roundcude:include file="/../setting/header.php"/>
```

Change to:

```
<roundcube:include file="/../setting/header.php"/>
```